# Does Databene benerator contain bugs or how is it set up?

Tags: exception, installation, generator

I just downloaded databene benerator version 0.8.1 and i'm using it on windows 7 starter. i need it to produce some test data for an application i'm developing, but it seems benerator is not working. I did set up the BENERATOR_HOME variable properly, but when i run `benerator -version` it prints the version details then throws an exception. this is the output on my console

```
C:\Users\Obby> benerator -version
Local classpath: .;D:\databene-benerator-0.8.1\bin;D:\databene-benerator-0.8.1\lib\*
12:56:16,874 INFO  (main) [CONFIG] Running file -version
12:56:16,890 INFO  (main) [CONFIG] Benerator 0.8.1 build 2335
12:56:16,890 INFO  (main) [CONFIG] Java version 1.7.0_17
12:56:16,890 INFO  (main) [CONFIG] JVM Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 23.7-b01 (Oracle     
Corporation)
12:56:16,905 INFO  (main) [CONFIG] OS Windows 7 6.1 (x86)
12:56:16,905 INFO  (main) [CONFIG] Installed JSR 223 Script Engines:
12:56:16,983 INFO  (main) [CONFIG] - Mozilla Rhino[js, rhino, JavaScript,     
javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript]
12:56:16,983 INFO  (main) [CONFIG] Max heap size: 247 MB
12:56:17,420 DEBUG (main) [CONFIG] Initializing Script mapping from file org/databene
/script/script.properties
Exception in thread "main" org.databene.commons.ConfigurationError: Error parsing  
-version
    at org.databene.commons.xml.XMLUtil.parse(XMLUtil.java:245)
    at org.databene.commons.xml.XMLUtil.parse(XMLUtil.java:235)
    at    
org.databene.benerator.engine.DescriptorRunner.parseDescriptorFile
(DescriptorRunner.java:113)
    at    
org.databene.benerator.engine.DescriptorRunner.runWithoutShutdownHook
(DescriptorRunner.java:109)
    at org.databene.benerator.engine.DescriptorRunner.run(DescriptorRunner.java:102)
    at org.databene.benerator.main.Benerator.runFile(Benerator.java:99)
    at org.databene.benerator.main.Benerator.runFromCommandLine(Benerator.java:82)
    at org.databene.benerator.main.Benerator.main(Benerator.java:75)
Caused by: org.databene.commons.ConfigurationError: Resource not found: -version
    at org.databene.commons.IOUtil.getResourceAsStream(IOUtil.java:584)
    at org.databene.commons.IOUtil.getFileOrResourceAsStream(IOUtil.java:565)
    at org.databene.commons.IOUtil.getInputStreamForURI(IOUtil.java:214)
    at org.databene.commons.IOUtil.getInputStreamForURI(IOUtil.java:198)
    at org.databene.commons.xml.XMLUtil.parse(XMLUtil.java:242)
    ... 7 more

C:\Users\Obby>
```

benerator environment variable is set up, i can get it properly on the console

```
C:\Users\Obby> echo %BENERATOR_HOME%
D:\databene-benerator-0.8.1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using two dashes before the argument 'version'.  One dash is conventionally used for single letter arguments.

Comment: thanks..the problem is that the documentation is old (for version 0.76) which says `-version`